# What is a command to find priority of process in Linux?

Tags: linux, process-management, priority

How can i view the priority of a specific process ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `top` command lists the priority of running processes under the `PR` heading. If you have it installed, you can also search for a process and sort by priority in `htop`.

Answer (score 24):

`awk '{print $18}' /proc/1337/stat` (gets the prio for process 1337).

If the command of the process has spaces in it, something like `awk '{print $(NF-34)}' /proc/1337/stat` to calculate the field position backwards from the number of fields could be used.

Other options:

Use `ps -o pri`. Specify the process id with `-p 1337`. Or, use `-e` to list all processes.

Experiment with this as a starting point if you want more than just the priority:

```
ps -e -o uid,pid,ppid,pri,ni,cmd
```

Comment: Note: `awk '{print $18}'` may return wrong result if `comm` (2nd field in `stat` file) contains a space.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @IrfanLatif. I updated the answer with one possible solution.

Answer (score 5):

`ps` is probably the right way to go. You can then grep and awk your way to the relevant row and column

Answer (score 5):

```
ps -o ni $(pidof processname)
```

For example:

```
ps -o ni $(pidof mysqld)

# ps -o ni $(pidof mysqld) 
  NI
  15
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a cut-down Linux distribution where ps and top does not give you priority information,  you can parse the stat file of proc for your process ID to get the priority information.

```
cat /proc/PID/stat | awk '{print "priority " $18 " nice " $19}'
```

The values at position 18 and 19 of stat file represent priority and nice

For more: https://linux.die.net/man/5/proc

Answer (score 0):

You might exclude headers with --no-headers if ps have it. You could use "ps --no-headers -o pri $(pidof )" to just show priority. Use pgrep if you have no pidof.